# How to create a timer for counting reservation time in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, timer

I've created a hotel room reservation website. Assume that a person who wants to reserve a room has 30 mins time to do that and after 30 mins the site would stop the reservation session for him; during this reservation he would pass several web page for filling the information. 
Is there any way to create a timer which can calculate 30 mins during SEVERAL PAGES?

Comment: I suppose the easiest thing would be to set a cookie when they begin the process and every time they change the page check to see if the expiry datetime in the cookie is still valid

Comment: Check each user action's timestamp instead and reject actions that have taken too long. That's how eg. airlines handle far larger reservation volumes.  You can't use a timer - each HTTP request executes on a different thread, which is reused once a request terminates. A timer started on one thread wouldn't be visible to the thread that handled a subsequent request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A timer would always get re-initialized when the user would reload the page after submitting the page unless you are having a *Single page application*.

Another simple way would be to store a cookie with the date time value when the user started filling in the forms (or what so ever is the initial stage). You can create it this way,

```
// Set the cookie
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("date");
// Add the value
cookie["dateValue"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
// Add the cookie
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Then you can check this cookie and (after successful casting to `DateTime` object) you can check whether user has some time in his 30 minutes trial period or whether he is late. You can get the cookie on the server-side using this code,

```
// This check would minimize one error
if(Request.Cookies["data"]["dateValue"] != null) {
   var time = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Cookies["data"]["dateValue"]);
} else {
   // Maybe cookie got removed.
}
```

This way you can set this functionality in your ASP.NET web application.

Comment: Thank you with your solution